# How to change the logout button to login in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have login and logout buttons that change dynamically after login.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="loginController">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href data-ng-show="token" ng-click="logout()"><b>Logout</b></a>
        <a href data-ng-hide="token" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So after I login, the button changes to logout using `ng-hide` but the same button doesn't change back to login after I log out?

Do I have to do a scope watch on the variables? I have the code like this using ui-router and states:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /login
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Login");

    var header = {
        templateUrl: 'views/Header.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }

    };
    var footer = {
        templateUrl: 'views/Footer.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    };
    // Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('Login', {
        url: "/Login",
        views: {
            header: header,
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'views/Login.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            },
            footer: footer
        }
    })
    .state('LoggedIn', {
        url: "/LoggedIn",
        views: {
            'header': header,
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/LoggedIn.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            },
            'footer': footer
        },
        data: {
            requiresLogin: true
        }
    });
```

Login controller where I am storing token in localstorage(as store in my case) to update the login/logout buttons using ng-show

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Auth', '$state', 'jwtHelper', 'store',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, Auth, $state, jwtHelper, store) {

        function successAuth(res) {
            var decodedToken  = jwtHelper.decodeToken(res.token);
            store.set('jwt', res.token);
            store.set('email', decodedToken.email);

            if (store.get('jwt')) {
                $state.go("LoggedIn");
            } else {
                alert("Invalid username or password");
            }
        }

        $scope.signup = function () {
            var formData = {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            };

            Auth.signup(formData, successAuth, function () {
                $rootScope.error = 'Failed to signup';
            });
        };

        $scope.logout = function ()
        {
            Auth.logout(function () {
                $state.go("Login");
                console.log("token after logout is :" + store.get('jwt'));
            });
        };
        $scope.token = store.get('jwt');
    }]);
```

Update:

Lets say after logging-in, Its routing from "Home" to "AboutUs" page with button shown as "Logout" and then if I logout it routes back to "Home" where the button is shown as "Login"

but the problem is after logging-in if I manually route to "Home" and then I click on "Logout" button, the button stays as "Logout" even when token is set to null;

Comment: What `console.log("token after logout is :" + store.get('jwt'));` logged ?What output of  `console.log($scope.token)` ?

Comment: Does not seems like you are removing token from the store when you logout, that's probably why the button is not changing

Comment: Token is being removed in Authservice

Comment: Removing token is not an issue. I am sure is removed on logout. I checked it

Comment: after logout what will be the value of `store.get('jwt')`

Comment: after logout the token is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by making following changes in html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="loginController">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href ng-if="isLogin" ng-click="logout()"><b>Logout</b></a>
        <a href ng-if="!isLogin" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And modification in javascript will be :

```
function successAuth(res) {
            var decodedToken  = jwtHelper.decodeToken(res.token);
            store.set('jwt', res.token);
            store.set('email', decodedToken.email);

            if (store.get('jwt')) {
                $state.go("LoggedIn");
                $scope.isLogin = true; // Added a new scope
            } else {
                alert("Invalid username or password");
            }
        }

$scope.logout = function ()
    {
        Auth.logout(function () {
            $state.go("Login");
            $scope.isLogin = false; // Added a new scope
            console.log("token after logout is :" + store.get('jwt'));
        });
    };

$scope.isLogin = !angular.isUndefined(store.get('jwt')); // Add this line also.
```

I hope it works for you.!!

Comment: But when you refresh the browser the boolean will be set to default right??

Comment: hey i have updated the same.
Can you please verify the same?

Comment: Hi Kunal...actually the token is null after logout.. pardon my bad

Comment: Updated the question. Please have a look at the problem I am facing.

Comment: your welcome. Please upvote it so that it will be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show in both the places or ng-hide in both places and on success of logout make the flag token opposite of what it currently is.That must work

Comment: Token is not boolean. Its a jwt token in storage

Comment: then add a boolean flag ANDed with the token